# Display percentages on piecharts python

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a pandas dataframe that describes the productivity (p = productivity) of some production line machine as a ratio of their activity time, wt (= working time) and the entire working shift they were supposed to be working, tt (= total time). The dataframe looks like this:

```
machines      tt          wt              p
1             7:30:00     4:30:00         0.60
2             7:30:00     3:30:00         0.50
3             6:00:00     5:24:00         0.90
...           ...         ...             ...
```

machines are strings
tt and wt are datetime.time
p are float64

I need to display on a dash dasboard the performance of the machines. Dash builds figures on plotly, so probably I will have to use plotly piecharts. I would like, for every machine, to have a piechart displaying the productivity of that specific machine. So one pie for each machine. I can't post pictures yet so I'll leave you the link of the desired solution. Output for each machine should look more or less like this

[click here to see the image of output needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqAUX.png)

**UPDATE**
After the exhaustive answer from @Rob Raymond I was wondering if there's any way to display the time a machine is active (or, respectively, lightblue area) when I go with the cursor on the blue area (or, respectively lightblue area). Do you know how to do that with dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use [subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) for a plot per machine
- you can layer an **Indicator** on top of **Pie** to achieve your output.  If **gauge** (semi-circle) works for you then you only need to use **Indicator**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""machines      tt          wt              p
m1             7:30:00     4:30:00         0.60
m2             7:30:00     3:30:00         0.50
m3             6:00:00     5:24:00         0.90"""),sep="\s+",)

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=len(df),
    subplot_titles=df["machines"].astype(str),
    specs=[[{"type": "pie"} for i in range(len(df))]],
)
for i, p in enumerate(df["p"]):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Pie(
            values=[1 - p, p],
            hole=0.6,
            showlegend=False,
            textinfo="none",
            hovertext=f"tt:{df.loc[i,'tt']}\twt:{df.loc[i,'wt']}",
            marker={"colors": ["lightblue", "blue"]},
        ),
        row=1,
        col=i + 1,
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Indicator(
            mode="number",
            value=p,
            gauge={"axis": {"visible": False}},
            number={"valueformat": "%", "font":{"size":30}},
        ),
        row=1,
        col=i + 1,
    )

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I got the point. One step further: what if I want the two times to be displayed when I go with my cursor on the image. With "two times" i mean (1) the time the machine was actively working (wt) when I go with the cursor on the blue area, and (2) the time the machine was not working (= tt - wt) when I go with my cursor on the lightblue area. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: updated - define **hovertext** to whatever you want